# Apache Metamodel vs Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill, apache-metamodel

Apache MetaModel is a data access framework that provides a common interface for the discovery, exploration, and querying of different types of data sources.

Apache Drill is a schema-free SQL query engine that delivers real-time insights by removing the constraint of building and maintaining schemas before data can be analyzed.

Anyone having insights on key difference between these two projects.I am getting confused since both are providing SQL like interface to query datastores

Thoughts please...

Answer (score 2):

The differences I can see:

1) Apache MetaModel is a library that one can embed in their own application to access multiple data sources. It does not have a shell/UI to add a data source and fire a query. Apache Drill on the other hand provides such a standalone client.

2) Apache Drill is supposed to be run on the cluster and be co-located with the data sources it accesses to avoid network transfer of large datasets. Apache MetaModel was not designed to be rolled out on a cluster, but to be run on a single machine.